# Decoding VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT token type in CBOR format

Tags: jackson, decode, fasterxml, cbor

I'm new to CBOR encoding format, doing POC to understand this format. I'm using [Faster XML library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary). Facing issue with one of the token type [VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken.html#VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT). I do not know how to parse this type object. Can anyone help in this regard?

thanks.

Comment: It appears to me this has nothing to do with CBOR.   I gather that this VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT token is specific to the JSON library you are using.

Comment: If your interest is really  learning about in CBOR, than I'd suggest using the [CBOR playground](http://cbor.me/), just paste your JSON in the left-hand pane (labeled diagnostic) and the CBOR representation will show on the right.